# Errors while using minidom.toprettyxml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom

I am converting CSV into XML. Input file myData.csv:

```
id,code name,value
36,abc,7.6
40,def,3.6
9,ghi,6.3
76,def,99
```

Python code works but the result is in one string with no line breaks and indents, so I modified it with the prettify, but it produces the error. Appreciate your insight into how to fix this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import csv
import sys
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import *
from xml.dom import minidom
def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
argvs = sys.argv

fileName = argvs[1]
with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    root = ET.Element('items')
    dataNum = len(header)
    for row in reader:
        item = ET.SubElement(root,'item')
        if len(row) == dataNum:
            for i in range(dataNum):
                node = ET.SubElement(item,header[i])
                node.text = str(row[i])

#xmlFile = ET.ElementTree(root)  # works but in one line, not pretty
xmlFile = prettify(root)       # does not work, error
xmlFile.write("./"+fileName.replace("csv","xml"))
```

Error:

```
python3 csvToXml-test.py myData.csv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvToXml-test.py", line 46, in <module>
    xmlFile = prettify(root)       # does not work, error
  File "csvToXml-test.py", line 17, in prettify
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1968, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had a space in the input file's header name. Took me 2 hours!